# User without permission can see the list with no items to show instead of Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.at shrepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

At microsoft sharepoint the permission of list is already updated, but user without permission still can see the list at left hand side quick launch, and when enter the link it shown with no items to show instead of Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Unexpected

[image]

Expected

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably added the list to a sitepage.
Permissions work differently for sitepages and apps.

If you grant a user permission to view a sitepage you implicitly grant the permission to view any webpart on that sitepage.
If the user does not have permission to view the contents of the app inside of the webpart, the app will display as having no content.

To get the error message you desire when no read permission was granted, you have to share the URL of your list.

Go to you site contents (gear icon top right corner) and click on your list. Now copy the URL from your navigation bar and share it with your users.

Comment: Tried to user the URL from navigation bar, but it still show There are no items to show in this view, really appreciate for your help

Comment: @elephantplan You have to use the URL to the app, not the sitepage. I described how to get it in my answer. Also, be sure you are setting permissions for the app and not for one list entry.

Comment: But there are some app inside that site I would like to share to this user, so i cannot set the permission blocked for whole site, instead i just edit the permission for that list

Comment: @elephantplan You can't do that in ootb SharePoint. And I can't think of a use-case for your proposed behaviour. You may need to restructure your apps so that they are not on a single sitepage.

Comment: Yes you are right, create a site page for that user instead of having permission in whole app and it's work. Thank you so much <3